# SqlAlchemy using one() then join() and values()

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter a criteria, and join two tables at the same time to handle user login. The username is in `Staff.staff_name` and the password is stored in `Staff_Authentication.staff_password`

```
        try:
            result = self.session.query(Staff).filter_by(staff_name=staff_name)\
                                .join(Staff_Authentication).one()\
                                .values(
                                        Staff.staff_id,
                                        Staff.staff_name,
                                        Staff_Authentication.staff_password,
                                        )
            if Staff_Authentication.check_password(staff_password, result.staff_password):
                # proceed to process valid login 
        except MultipleResultsFound as e:
            raise InvalidParameter("More than one pair of these name and password pair")
        except NoResultFound as e:
            raise InvalidParameter("No such user")
```

This results in the error

```
AttributeError: 'Staff' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I have tried to move `one()` to right after `filter_by()`, and the result is similar

```
AttributeError: 'Staff' object has no attribute 'join'
```

How can I chain `join()` or `values()` after using `one()`?

Answer (score 1):

Methods like `one()`, `first()` and `all()` are final. You must use them after everything else.

```
        try:
            result = self.session.query(Staff).filter_by(staff_name=staff_name) \
                            .join(Staff_Authentication) \
                            .values(
                                    Staff.staff_id,
                                    Staff.staff_name,
                                    Staff_Authentication.staff_password,
                                    ) \
                            .one()
        if Staff_Authentication.check_password(staff_password, result.staff_password):
            # proceed to process valid login 
    except MultipleResultsFound as e:
        raise InvalidParameter("More than one pair of these name and password pair")
    except NoResultFound as e:
        raise InvalidParameter("No such user")
```